How to Pin anything to Start Button in Windows 11 .bat .vbs .docx .pdf
For adding items that are not applications, I Googled my questions and only came up with convoluted ways of adding pinned items to the start button or, I couldn't find any answer at all. e.g.
How to pin a vbs file to start windows 11,
How to pin a batch file to start windows 11,
How to pin a pdf file to start windows 11,
How to pin a word file to start windows 11,
How to pin an excel file to start windows 11

Not sure about windows 11 compatibility but Tileiconifier audible on GitHub allows you to create and modify tiles

Use this method to add an item to the Start button's Pinned section for anything that you want to run or open from the Start button.
Put the item you want Pinned in the folder below or create a shortcut for the item you want Pinned and put it in the folder below (where Pinned items are stored for your profile).  NOTE: at the time of writing this article, Internet Shortcuts made with Chrome Version 131.0.6778.86 didn't work for me (not sure about Internet Shortcuts made with older versions of Chrome).  I had to make Internet Shortcuts using Microsoft Edge (those Shortcuts could be Pinned).
C:\Users\[YOUR PROFILE ID]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
Initially the item will not be visible in the Start button's Pinned area.  To make it visible, press the Start button then, enter the name of item you created into the search, and the search will find the item.  If you right click on the item, that's been found in the search, you will see the option to pin it i.e.: Pin to Start
Example: made a .vbs file (OpenFoldersInFileExplorer.vbs), made a shortcut and put it where Pinned items are stored, searched for it, and pinned it:

